# Xcode and git-lfs

Tags: xcode, git, git-lfs

I installed `git-lfs` using `homebrew`, and it works fine from the command line. I can still add text files in Xcode as well, but whenever I try in Xcode to add a file which should be tracked by `git-lfs`, there is no effect (the file stays "?" in Xcode's file list, and the command line confirms that the file was not, in fact, added). After some research, I tried adding `~/Library/LaunchAgents/my.startup.plist` to `setenv PATH /usr/local/bin` but it had no effect.

How can I get Xcode to play nice with `git-lfs`?

Answer (score 8):

We have a similar issue, our CI uses Xcode's git and not the homebrew one. So we needed to get git-lfs working in Xcode. This proved pretty simple: copying the git-lfs core file from the homebrew version into Xcode (you need to do this again every time you upgrade Xcode):

```
sudo ln -s `which git-lfs` /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-lfs
```

Edited to highlight great improvement by @blackjack75.

Comment: Same in an one-liner finding the current git `sudo ln -s \`which git-lfs\` /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-lfs`

Comment: Or even better when you have multiple Xcode versions on the machine and it is not named Xcode.app `sudo ln -s \`which git-lfs\` \`xcode-select -p\`/usr/libexec/git-core/git-lfs`

Answer (score 6):

There seem to be a problem with using git-lfs with Xcode. See this article:
http://gopalkri.com/2016/05/17/git-lfs-xcode-asset-catalogs/

Might be better off to stick with Git to commit your changes instead of doing it via Xcode.

Comment: 3 years later and it still seems to be an issue.. Any updates?

Comment: Still a problem in 2023.